# Program that receives 2 arrays and checks how many times 1 is included in the other

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that receives 2 arrays and checks how many times 1 is included in the other...
But I cant find what is wrong with my program! tx!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vector1[500];
    int vector2[100];
    int a = 0, b = 0, count = 0, k = 0;
    cout << "enter size of first array:" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << " enter first array values:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        cin >> vector1[i];
    cout << "enter size of second array:" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "enter secound array values:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        cin >> vector2[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            if (vector2[i + k] == vector1[j])
            {
                count++;
                k++;
            }
            else
                k = 0;


    cout << count << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program is extremely easy to open a security hole in. You need to declare the size of the array after you ask the user big the array will be, or add a maximum value to the array size the user can enter. In fact, do both so that your program will be safe from buffer overflow, consume the minimum amount of memory needed, and not have ridiculously large arrays because the user decided to type "987654321"

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly While true, i doubt the asker is developing a program that will be on anyone's computer ...

Comment: @Ben It's never to early to start writing secure programs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why at all do you need k? The problem is about all inclusions of all elements right? If O(n^2) complexity is fine, then...

```
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        if (vector2[i] == vector1[j])
            count++;
```

One obvious disadvantage of the code above is that you'll get the *total* sum of all occurences of elements from vector1 in vector2. The key idea remains the same in case you need to know, which elements exactly appeared in another array and how many times, you'll just have to use map or other vector.

Comment: Do you need to count repeated inclusions? I would rather advise taking an unordered_map<> with keys = values from second array, loop the first one, increase values in this map each time you find the proper key. 
After filling the map the answer is the smallest value in it.